# Print jobs disappear from spool queue

Tags: c#, printing, spool

I'm coding a C# application to print PDF on local printer and redirect printing task on a network printer if the local one fails.

Problem : when I send a task to the local printer through windows spool, the job disappears from the spool after few seconds even if the printer have an error (eg out of paper). Whereas, if I put paper in the printer after this fail, the document is printed (but still not shown in the spool).

It seems that the printer buffers the printing task even if it doesn't work...

Here is my code for printing :

```
// using PdfiumViewer;

public static void PrintPdf(string path, ManagementObject printer)
{
    PdfDocument doc = PdfDocument.Load(path);
    PrintDocument pd = doc.CreatePrintDocument();

    pd.PrinterSettings.FromPage = 1;
    pd.PrinterSettings.ToPage = doc.PageCount;
    pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printer["Name"].ToString();

    ClearPrintQueue(printer["Name"].ToString());

    if ((bool)printer["WorkOffline"])
        throw new UnavailablePrinterException("L'imprimante est hors ligne.");
    else
        pd.Print();
}
```

How can I avoid printer buffering or at least detect job fail and cancel it ?

Comment: This is entirely normal behavior for the System.Printing namespace.  Originally not deemed useful enough to be included with .NET 2.0, it should have stayed that way.  But unfortunately WPF took a dependency on it.  There is nothing you can do about this, other than yelling at it and *never* using it.

Comment: @HansPassant So how can i do without using it ?

Comment: Billions of documents are printed every week, millions of printers run out of paper, without ever needing the "help" of System.Printing.  You'll learn to live without it.